How to add reactivity to Input parameters
This question relates to Angular 17.1 - I appreciate other options may be available in later versions of the framework
I have a parent component that retrieves some parameters from its URL and then feeds these into a child component which is responsible for retrieving and displaying the results of an API call based on these parameters. Users can overtype the URL parameters so the child component needs to be able to cope with changes to them after initialization:
@Input({required: true}) public param1!: number;
...


When these values change I want to make an api call and have that stream available for the template.
I've tried a few approaches:
//use subject
@Input({required: true}) 
public set param1(value: number){
   this.param1Subject.next(value)
}

public data$ = this.param1Subject.pipe(switchMap(param => this.apiService.getData(param))


Unfortuantely the subject emits its first value too early in the lifecycle before the async pipe in my template starts observing it.  As a result I lose the initial value
Option 2 was to use a signal
@Input({required: true}) 
public set param1(value: number){
   this.param1Signal.set(value);
}

constructor(){
  effect(()=>{
    public data$ = this.apiService.getData(this.paramSignal())
  }
}

}



Is it an anti-pattern to be changing component state within the effect?
I feel like there is a third option where I use toObservable() on the signal and switchMap from that, but then I'll have an input param, signal and observable all set up just to handle changes to param1.
I'm missing something really simple here.  Any thoughts?

Here : Signal as observable source and getting back observable to signal
import { Component, Input, effect, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { toObservable, toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';
import { Observable, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
   <h2>Angular 17+</h2>
   <button (click)="updateParam1Input()">click to see</button>
   <br>
   <!-- Signal as observable stream -->
    <div *ngIf="data();">
      <small>Signal as observable stream :</small>
      {{data() }}

    <!-- Direct signal -->
      <br>
      <small>Direct signal :</small>
      {{this.param1() }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  // Input as a writable signal
  param1 = signal<number>(0);

  //On Input change ->It is updating signal 'param1' value
  @Input({ required: true }) set param1Input(value: number) {
    this.param1.set(value);
  }

  // Observable from signal
  private param1$ = toObservable(this.param1);

  // Use switchMap to create a new observable that updates when param1 changes
  private data$: Observable<any> = this.param1$.pipe(
    switchMap((param) => this.apiHit(param))
  );

  // Convert the observable back to a signal to use in template
  data = toSignal(this.data$, { initialValue: null });

  constructor() {
    // Optional: Log changes to param1
    //whenever signal changes, effect detects it
    effect(() => {
      console.log('param1 changed:', this.param1());
    });
  }

  //apiHit service to call another service api
  public apiHit(param: number) {
    console.log('Getting called when signal "param1" value changes');
    return of(param);
  }

  //change @Input value on btn click
  public updateParam1Input() {
    //This @Input() event on changes will change the value of signal 'param1' variable
    this.param1Input = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);
  }
}


When thinking from signals perspective, we can use toObservable to convert the signal to an observable stream and then use switchMap to switch to the API call, this is the easiest method.
import { input } from '@angular/core';
import { toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

param1 = input.required();
api$ = toObservable(this.param1).pipe(
    switchMap(param => this.apiService.getData(param)),
);

HTML:
 @for (item of (api$ | async); track item) {
        {{ item }}
 } @empty {
        Empty list of items
 } 


A non signal approach is to use ngOnChanges to detect input change and trigger the API call again.
@Input({required: true}) public param1!: number;
param1Subject = new Subject();
public data$ = this.param1Subject.pipe(switchMap(param => this.apiService.getData(param))
...
ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
  const param1 = changes?.['param1'];
  if(param1 && param1.previousValue != param1.currentValue ) {
   this.param1Subject.next(param1.currentValue)
  }
}

You can also get rid of the if condition inside ngOnChanges since when using a primitive for param1 like string, numer, etc. We can be sure that the value has changed when ngOnChanges has fired. If you are using non primitive datatypes then you must have the if condition and track if the actual object has changed, we can use lodash isEqual for this.
I am using Subject instead of BehaviourSubject, since it does not emit a first value, during the initial subscription.

Thanks for the options - do you have a view on whether handling the change in an effect is an anti-pattern?

@royneedshelp You need to avoid setting a signal inside the effect that is the only problem, other than that you can achieve the same with effect, let me know if you need that also!
